# Two inserts in one function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i build a function with two insert statements. The first one only insert two name fields into a table and the second one reads an id field from the first one which is create via insert statement automatically increment on the database.

Is it a correct way to do this?

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'groupname' => 'required|unique:groups,group_name'
    ]);

    $groups_create = new Group();
    $groups_create->group_name = $request->input('groupname');
    $groups_create->group_admin = Auth::id();
    $groups_create->save();

    $groupid = Group::where('group_name', $request->input('groupname'))->select('idgroups')->first();

    $groups_create_subscription = new GroupSubscription();
    $groups_create_subscription->idgroups = $groupid->idgroups;
    $groups_create_subscription->subscriber = Auth::id();
    $groups_create_subscription->save();

    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Ihre Gruppe wurde angelegt!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your current code as such:

```
$group = Group::create([
    'group_name' => $request->input('groupname'),
    'group_admin' => Auth::id()
]);

GroupSubscription::create([
    'idgroups' => $group->idgroups,
    'subscriber' => Auth::id()
]);
```

because now, we can cut out the complete `Group::where` query and we can guarantee that you are getting the correct incremented ID.

You could also use [transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions).

Answer (score 0):

When saved more then one item in db you mast be use database transaction.

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'groupname' => 'required|unique:groups,group_name'
    ]);

    DB::beginTransaction();
    $groups_create = new Group();
    $groups_create->group_name = $request->input('groupname');
    $groups_create->group_admin = Auth::id();
    $groups_create->save();

    if (!$groups_create->save()) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect('home')->with('danger', 'Group not saved!');
    }

    $groupid = Group::where('group_name', $request->input('groupname'))->select('idgroups')->first();

    $groups_create_subscription = new GroupSubscription();
    $groups_create_subscription->idgroups = $groupid->idgroups;
    $groups_create_subscription->subscriber = Auth::id();

    if (!$groups_create_subscription->save()) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect('home')->with('danger', 'Group not saved!');
    }

    DB::commit();
    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Ihre Gruppe wurde angelegt!');
}
```

also you can use for saving this structure. See official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

```
$data = [
    'group_name' => $request->input('groupname'),
    'group_admin' => Auth::id()
];

$groups_create Group::craete($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### #1 (Simple)

No need to make new query to find `$groupid`. You can get `$groupid` like this :

```
$groups_create              = new Group();
$groups_create->group_name  = $request->input('groupname');
$groups_create->group_admin = Auth::id();
$groups_create->save();

$groups_create_subscription             = new GroupSubscription();
$groups_create_subscription->idgroups   = $group_create->idgroups;
$groups_create_subscription->subscriber = Auth::id();
```

---

#### #2 (Database Transactions)

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $groups_create              = new Group();
    $groups_create->group_name  = $request->input('groupname');
    $groups_create->group_admin = Auth::id();
    $groups_create->save();

    $groups_create_subscription             = new GroupSubscription();
    $groups_create_subscription->idgroups   = $group_create->idgroups;
    $groups_create_subscription->subscriber = Auth::id();

    DB::commit();

    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Ihre Gruppe wurde angelegt!');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();

    return redirect('home')->with('danger', 'Group not saved!');
}
```

---

#### #3 (Defining Relationships)

> Eloquent relationships are defined as methods on your Eloquent model classes. Since, like Eloquent models themselves, relationships also serve as powerful query builders, defining relationships as methods provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities

***Group model***

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GroupSubscription', 'idgroups', 'idgroups');
    }
}
```

***GroupSubscription model***

```
class GroupSubscription extends Model
{
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Group', 'idgroups', 'idgroups');
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```
$groups_create              = new Group();
$groups_create->group_name  = $request->input('groupname');
$groups_create->group_admin = Auth::id();
$groups_create->save();

$groups_create->subscriptions()->create([
    'subscriber' => Auth::id(),
]);

// It will automaticaly set idgroups
```

---

#### #4 (Naming Conventions)

Follow [PSR standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Also, follow [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) accepted by Laravel community.

Comment: #1 Simple: Your code is not working. When I do this I get Null for $group_create->idgroups; Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: Is `idgroups` a primary key?

Comment: Yes, idgroups is primary key.

Comment: It work like a charm on my mac. Can you show me full model and controller?

Comment: My model is only protected $table = 'groups';

Comment: How Laravel know your primary key?

Comment: Does Laravel have to know that? But why? Primary key is defined in the mysql table.